# How to use PHP and Mysql to display different items with only one webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, web

My e-business website is actually a search engine.

Step 1 :
    users can search the item they like by key words or other attributes.

Step 2: 
    After that, user may find the items they like, and click on the title of a specific item (or picture,etc) to activate a hyperlink.

Step 3:
    Then a webpage that describes the detail of the item will appear.

I was stuck in Step 3.

I found that there are more than 10 thousand items in MySQL database. I wondered if I need to create more than 10 thousand webpages to describe the details for each items ?(Of course it is impractical, but I don't know how to build only one webpage to solve this problem).

p.s. An idea has once come into my mind that I can build a share webpage for describing the detail of items, and find a way to detect which hyperlink or item user have clicked on, but I haven't learn this skill. Is it possible, or there is a better way?

Comment: There are like a billion tutorials out there about it

Comment: Link to a script like `details.php`, and pass the database id of the product as a GET parameter - `details.php?product=1234`. Then in that script you read that parameter, and make a database query that gets the record/details for that id.

Comment: You can create a php function that search in your data with the name of the item and then send it to your web page , so the user when click on an item the web page send to your php file the name of the item and the php file send to the data base this name and search for it and when it find you send it to your web page and show it.

Comment: `only one webpage` to make it clear, you can create one page like `www.mysite.com/items/details` and show million products there e.g. `www.mysite.com/items/details/?item=1`  or `www.mysite.com/items/details/item_1` or `www.mysite.com/items/details/item/1/bag-for-ipad`. It depends on the API behind your webpage!! So your question is very vage. One weppage dont mean there is only one script behind it.

Comment: Well you can just add the id of each product to the end of the link like : ?id=x and just create one description.php page and get the id and search for it in your database and return the description to that page !

Comment: Create ProductDetails.php (which have product details display design) now in the top of this page write script for fetch details form product id. now from any other page you can parse the product id and receive it on the ProductDetails page using $_GET param(hope you know the concepts how to use) and its done for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need like 3 pages:

1. index.php
2. results.php
3. detail.php

In detail.php, you'll need to build a query to get the appropriate information about the item.

You could create for each result a unique link, by adding its id to the url:

```
detail.php?id=23 // for example
```

Then on the detail page, you can catch the id like this, and query the database to get all the information about that product:

```
// Get the product id
product_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;

// Check if product id is set
if ($product_id) :
    // Query the database and make a template to display your product info here
endif;
```

This should give you an idea on how to do it basicly.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that in your case, when the user click the info button you'll have to pass an identificator via GET or POST. That way you only will need one page in step 3, then you populate the description of that item accordingly to that especific ID.

More info on passing variables in php is avaliable [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here an example, use pdo:

```
$ID = $_GET['id']; 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=dbname","user","password");
    $st =$conn->prepare("SELECT ID FROM `items` WHERE ID =:ID");
    $st->bindParam(':ID',$ID);
    $st->execute();
    $row=$st->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then display items.

**note:** If you want show more than one table do the same but change SQL.